# How to restore standard menu bar (File, Edit, View, Insert, Format, etc.) in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base, libreoffice-writer

[image: LibreOffice Writer missing the Main Menu bar]

libreoffice-6.0.7  on Ubuntu Bionic

After purging and reinstalling what I thought was a corrupted version of LibreOffice, it seems that the "Main Menu" of LibreOffice has been deprecated. What I see now are just graphical toolbars of what looks almost like full-screen mode and the "close document" "x" button is oddly on the left now. I know that Firefox and other applications have begun hiding the "File, Edit, View" menu by default. I have no frame of reference of this on LibreOffice. Older solutions suggested that this was due to corrupted profiles, but after purging dot-configs that does not seem to be the case.

I don't know if this is a brilliant improvement to the interface or if the menu is now hidden.

Is there a way restore the main menu?

I deleted dot-configs. I purged and reinstalled. If I had accidentally hidden the main menu, it should have been unhidden by default on a new installation.

Comment: Better move this question to [su], however, if you have a drop down on the right named "menu", open it and use the "user interface" entry. (Wording might be different, as I use a non-English LibreOffice.)

Comment: After moving this question to a different site such as Super User or Ask Ubuntu, please tell your operating system and version of LibreOffice. Also mention if you are using the tabbed interface or the standard toolbar. A picture of the upper right hand corner of the window may help to answer that question. Also the `libreoffice-basic` tag is not relevant as this question is not about macros, and the Base tag doesn't seem needed either.